# Can an Access Token from a Different Issuer be Used for the Microsoft Graph On Behalf of Flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I've been following Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) where a client can call a middle tier API using an access token which in turn uses the same access token as an assertion to obtain an access token from Microsoft Graph (the downstream API) to be able to call Graph API's.

My question is, does that access token from the client *have* to come from Microsoft? If not (for instance, our access tokens come from an on premises Identity Server), how does Microsoft verify the authenticity of the access token from the client?

Answer (score 1):

The access token needs to come from Azure AD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Comment: The link, if I understand correctly, is talking about getting an access token for Graph API's directly, but I'm referring to using an access token from a client to then get another access token from a middle tier API for Graph.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the definition of OBO flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

> For the middle-tier service to make authenticated requests to the downstream service, it needs to secure an access token from the Microsoft identity platform, on behalf of the user.

I.e. the original token must have come from AAD to be used for exchange for another token.